# viewpager swiping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, text-to-speech, swipe

the below code is working from left to right swiping now i would like set `the` same thing from the right to left also.swiping is working but the speakout is getting crashed with position.in pageAdapter forward swiping is working good.and backward swiping is also working good only but Textto speech is not correctly working

Below is the code:

```
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ImageView image=new ImageView(context);
               image.setImageResource(fruits[position]);
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(image);
              if(position>=1){
                  image.setImageResource(fruits[position]);
                  speakOut(names[position-1]);
              }
              return image;
            }
```

here its not working. can any one give me suggestions and take me out of this issue

```
   public class Learn extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
        private TextToSpeech tts;
        private ViewPager pic;
        private Button next,back;
        private TextView text;
        private Context context;
        private int i=0;
        public Integer[] fruits={R.drawable.apple1,R.drawable.banana1,R.drawable.grapes1,R.drawable.cherry1,R.drawable.lemon1,
                R.drawable.orange1,R.drawable.strwberry1,R.drawable.water1};
        public String [] names={"Apple","Banana","Grapes","Cherry","Lemon","Orange","Strawberry","Water melon"};

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.learn);
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            pic=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            ImagePageAdapter adapterpic=new ImagePageAdapter(this);
            pic.setAdapter(adapterpic);

        }
        private class ImagePageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            public ImagePageAdapter(Context learn) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                context=learn;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return names.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
              return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ImageView image=new ImageView(context);
               image.setImageResource(fruits[position]);
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(image);
              if(position>=1){
                  image.setImageResource(fruits[position]);
                  speakOut(names[position-1]);
              }
              return image;
            }
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
              ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
            }

        }
        private void speakOut(String text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
            if (tts != null) {
                tts.stop();
                tts.shutdown();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

           if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                } else {
                    pic.setEnabled(true);

                    //speakOut("apple");
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            }

        }
    }
    Here is stack trace

02-27 16:39:00.994: I/TTS received:(2369): Apple
02-27 16:39:05.144: I/TTS received:(2369): Banana
02-27 16:39:06.534: I/TTS received:(2369): Grapes
02-27 16:39:24.273: I/TTS received:(2369): Banana
02-27 16:39:25.355: I/TTS received:(2369): Grapes
02-27 16:39:26.593: I/TTS received:(2369): Cherry
02-27 16:39:28.624: I/TTS received:(2369): Apple
```

please give me suggestions to get out of this issue

Comment: i suggest that adding a stack trace might help

Comment: 02-27 14:03:31.824: W/KeyCharacterMap(2013): No keyboard for id 0
02-27 14:03:31.824: W/KeyCharacterMap(2013): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-27 14:03:45.623: I/TTS received:(2013): Apple
02-27 14:03:48.293: I/TTS received:(2013): Banana
02-27 14:03:49.543: I/TTS received:(2013): Grapes
02-27 14:03:51.473: I/TTS received:(2013): Cherry
02-27 14:03:53.353: I/TTS received:(2013): Lemon
02-27 14:03:56.254: I/TTS received:(2013): Banana
02-27 14:03:58.534: I/TTS received:(2013): Apple

Comment: @priyamadhuri please edit your post and put the full stack trace in there.

Comment: @Warpzit i kept full stack trace

Comment: @priyamadhuri yes but you put it in comment instead of editing your own post. Now edit you post and put full stack trace in there.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to put sounds of objects instead of convert them text to speech.. You can try this code

```
public class Learn extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,R.drawable.no10,R.drawable.bg2};

private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,R.raw.ten,R.raw.one};

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
         return mImages.length;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
         return view == ((ImageView) object);
         }

         @Override
         public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Numbers.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding =context.getResources().  
            getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 
            if(position>=1){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[position-1]);
            mp.start();
            }
            return imageView;
         }

          @Override
         public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
           ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
         }
     }
     }
```

Here value you can change according to your requirements.